# How to unique Indexes in combination of columns in Squeryl

Tags: scala, squeryl

How can i define unique constraints in combination of columns in squeryl schema?

```
A  |  B  
2     1  allow
2     3  allow
3     1  allow
2     1  don't allow same with row one
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
on(authors)(s => declare(      
   columns(s.firstName, s.lastName) are(unique) 
))
```

http://squeryl.org/schema-definition.html